# How do I read a csv file that is on the downloads directory of a mobile device, for an Android application

Tags: android, csv

How do we code to get the "Open from" dialog, on an Android device?

I can find many source code examples for reading a csv file, especially when located in the res\raw directory, but I could find no example of how to have an Android app issue a dialog to read the Downloads directory and select a csv file stored in it.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: "issue a dialog to read the Downloads directory and select a csv file stored in it."  I don't understand what that means.  Do you mean read the contents of the downloads directory, present them to the user as a list, and let them select one?

Comment: I want to be able to issue a dialog that will allow for selecting a file from the downloads directory on a mobile device.

Comment: Why a dialog?  That doesn't sound like a very good tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found hints to the solution in an article entitled [Android Import excel into Sqlite Database Part 1](http://www.parallelcodes.com/android-import-excel-into-sqlite-database/)

To get that dialog:

```
Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
fileIntent.setType("text/csv")
try {
    startActivityForResult(fileIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
     } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No app found for importing the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

where REQUEST_CODE is 1.

You can then later on access the selected file by:

```
String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
```